# how to spin back the icon when click on it twice

Tags: javascript, html

the code given below is used to create a sidebar menu.i have two drop down menus inside that 'apps' and 'layout' and two drop down icons are attached with both.i want to rotate back the icon when click on the icon twice.what i need to be attached/modified with this code to implement such a drop down menu.

```js
function rotateIcon(m) {
    var key=m;
    if(key===2)
        {
            document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon in fa fa-caret-down";
            document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down";
        }
    else if(key===3)
        {
            document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon in fa fa-caret-down";
            document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down";
        }
    else{
            document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down";
            document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down";
    }
}
```

```css
.spinner-icon{
        /*float: right;
        padding-right: 5%;*/
        margin-top: 5%;
        /*margin-left:3rem;*/
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.spinner-icon.in{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.spinner-icon.out{
    transform:rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<li class="flip-container-main-menu-parent" id="flip-main-one" onclick="rotateIcon(1);"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-glass "></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Dashboard</span></li>
                    <li class="flip-container-main-menu-parent" id="flip-main-two" onclick="rotateIcon(2);"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-th"></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Apps</span> <i id="first-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-caret-down"></i> </li>
<li class="flip-container-main-menu-parent" id="flip-main-three" onclick="rotateIcon(3);"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-th-large"></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Layout</span><i id="second-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-caret-down"></i>  </li>              
<li class="flip-container-main-menu-parent" id="flip-main-four"onclick="rotateIcon(4);"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-align-justify"></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Widjet</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to Rotate back the icon

```js
function rotateIcon(m) {
  var res = m;
  if (res == "first-drop-down-icon") {

    if (document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className == "spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down") {

      document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon in fa fa-caret-down";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down";
    }


  } else {
    if (document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className == "spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down") {

      document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon in fa fa-caret-down";
       document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down";
    }
  }



}
```

```css
.spinner-icon {
  /*float: right;
        padding-right: 5%;*/
  /*margin-left:3rem;*/
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.spinner-icon.in {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.spinner-icon.out {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 3%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<li class="flip-container-main-menu-parent" id="flip-main-one"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-glass "></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Dashboard</span>
</li>
<li class="flip-container-main-menu-parent" id="flip-main-two" onclick="rotateIcon('first-drop-down-icon');"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-th"></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Apps</span>  <i id="first-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down"></i> 
</li>
<li class="flip-container-main-menu-parent" id="flip-main-three" onclick="rotateIcon('second-drop-down-icon');"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-th-large"></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Layout</span><i id="second-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon out fa fa-caret-down"></i> 
</li>
<li class="flip-container-main-menu-parent" id="flip-main-four"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-align-justify"></i><span class="flip-menu-text">Widjet</span>
</li>
```

Comment: tnx for your help.but which has been lost it's old functionality(ie, when click on the second icon the first icon is return to old position).check question.tnx any way.

Comment: @WhiteMaskers now i edited the code,is it working fine like the previous functionality

Comment: @annalakshmi ,sorry..(check this first click on apps then on  dashboard)     according to question the drop down menu on apps need to be turned back,but it is not working on the above code